# Use mouse 'on click' instead of 'mouse over' event, jquery

Tags: jquery, mousehover, onmouseclick

I have this script [here](http://webarchive.gr/test111.html) which works fine, but I need to make it work on mouse click instead of mouse hover.

I have tried, but failed. It looks simple, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

code is:

```
$(".cat").hover(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").hide();
},
function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").show();
});`
```

code below works in ie, not in firefox.

```
$(".cat").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Could you please add the code that doesn't work to the question? (Click the "edit" button just beneath the tags.) That means that the question will still be useful in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(".cat").on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").toggle();
});
```

You can replace the .parent() by using `.closest()` if the HTML structure is known..

OR

```
$(".cat").on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest('.menu').find(".sub_menu").toggle();
 });
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sJbbZ/)**

Comment: Adeneo's solution doesn't work in firefox(works in ie), so i'll go with Sushanth's .closest(). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".cat").on('click', function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".sub_menu").toggle();
});
```