# Maintain div state of toggle event

Tags: jquery, state

In addition to [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078782/use-mouse-on-click-instead-of-mouse-over-event-jquery) about a click event on multiple div tags with same class, is there a way to maintain div's state after page refresh, using jquery? 
I've done this in the past but for checkboxes and NOT with same class div tags. I also checked other posts, unfortunately they don't work for me.

Comment: local storage or cookies will do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to save the state somewhere that's not on the page (in a cookie or on the server) then restore the page using that saved state.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use cookies if you want to maintain any state after page load or you can use local storage if you are using HTML5.